# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment

Tags: errors, alignment, badness

In my thesis I wanted to have the members of the equations as following: [image] 
So I found this way of creating it:

```
\newlength{\conditionwd}
\newenvironment{variables}[1][on\quad]
{%
#1\tabularx{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}[t]{
 >{$}l<{$} @{${}:\enspace{}$} l>{(}l<{)}@{}
}%
}
{\endtabularx\\[\belowdisplayskip]}
```

So in the example of the picture would be this one:

```
    \begin{variables}
        Q   & Transferència de calor                            & \si{\watt}\\
        k   & Conductivitat tèrmica del material                & \si{\watt\per\meter\per\kelvin}\\
        A   & Àrea de la superfície de bescanvi                 & \si{\square\metre}\\
        T   & Temperatura                                       & \si{\kelvin}\\
        x   & Profunditat superfície                            & \si{\metre}\\
        -   & Expressa direcció calor de zona calenta a freda   &
    \end{variables}
```

The problem is that as you can see in the following picture, it appears an error at the last line of the code, with the **Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)**.

[image]

Although the code work, the error annoys me and I could't find a way to fix it. I was wondering if anyone more experienced could see what produced the error and help me fixing it.

Comment: It's a warning, and not an error

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin but it is a warning of _maximum_ badness, due to an error in the code

Comment: you have used a tabularx, specifying a width but not used an X column so it has no way to achieve the width so is necessarily underfull. as there is no line breaking in the table, just use a normal `tabular` here not `tabularx`.  (please always provide a test document not disconnected fragments that can not be tested)